# Как исправить цикл чтобы избежать RecursionError?

Tags: python, циклы, рекурсия

Есть цикл:

```
def F(n):
    if n == 1:
        return F(1)
    else:
        if n > 1:
            return F(n-1) + 2**(n-1)

print(F(10))
```

При вызове функции получаю ошибку:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`
Как можно изменить цикл, чтобы получить значение и избежать этой ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eсли n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то выполнить функцию F c аргументом n=1, в которой если n равно 1, то...

Нужно `return F(1)` заменить на `return 1`.